# Find Referenes to Symbol Under Cursor on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

On QtCreator C++ project if we right click on a function name a menu will pop up, one of the options there is `Find Referenes to Symbol Under Cursor` which will then report where that function is being used.

Is there something similar in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you right click a function name in VS, there is **Find All References** context menu item.